# Autocomplete Pycharm Pro 2017.1

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, pycharm

Dev. Box: Windows 7
Remote Box where project should be deployed: Redhat Linux

Project on remote machine does not utilise pip or virtualenv  but rather an in house alternative to virtualenv.

I setup my remote interpreter in Pycharm via Ssh to the python interpreter in linux box and see all the modules on remote with version info listed.

Pycharm tries initially to upload Pycharm helpers to remote box but is I guess unable to install them as I imagine it cannot find usual python tools like pip, so I see a banner on the remote interpreter saying Setup tools not present on remote. Regardless when this preference window is closed pycharm initiates indexing I assume the remote interpreter and modules.

When I open a file in the code however after indexing completes I cannot get auto code complete to work for any module even standard library modules i.e. json, sys, os...

I tried to get more info on Pycharm Helpers that try to get installed but all I found was they get used for remote debugging and "scaffolding" which I can't find additional details as to what the latter means or if it is even relevant to get autocomplete to function.

Need help really badly on this, thanks in advance to anyone who can aide me in this matter.

Some collegues got around this by having Devbox be a Mac OS or any other linux distribution, cloning the project locally and then using the local interpreter option in Pycharm but unfortunately I can't utilise local interpreter even though the project is cloned because on windows Pycharm expects the local interpreter to be a .exe